# IAM issue with Google Cloud Run service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-automl, identity-management

I am trying to deploy my AutoML trained model using Cloud Run, but am having difficulties with IAM permissions. I'm using [this as a guide](https://medium.com/@juri.sarbach/how-to-deploy-your-automl-model-in-a-cost-effective-way-5efdd377d4d2), and keep getting the following error at the build step. I'm new to Cloud Run/GCP but as far as I can see, I have granted the right roles to the right accounts. I appreciate any assistance you can provide as I'm really stumped.

Error message:

```
Step #3: ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) User [REDACTED@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access namespaces instance [REDACTED] (or it may not exist): 

Google Cloud Run Service Agent does not have permission to get access tokens for the service account REDACTED@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com. 

Please give service-REDACTED@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com permission iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken on the service account. 

Alternatively, if the service account is unspecified or in the same project you are deploying in, ensure that the Service Agent is assigned the Google Cloud Run Service Agent role roles/run.serviceAgent.
```

Here are the roles assigned to the Cloud Run Service Agent
[image]

Default service account has the Cloud Run Admin Role
[image]

Here are the accounts to which I've given access to the Default compute service account, the Cloud Build Service Agent and Cloud Run Service Agent are added:
[image]

Comment: Did you try the Owner role ? To see if this works with over privileged service account

Comment: I just tried that, gave Owner role to the default service account and it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Can you try running this command in your Google Cloud shell ? ```gcloud config list``` Just to check if you set the project correctly, If the issue persists I would suggest contacting Google Cloud Support if you are eligible for support. Alternatively you can report this issue in Google's Issue Tracker, See steps here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: I was able to fix this, I had the wrong service account in my cloudbuild.yaml file. Thanks both for the advice.